# CORPUS resource

Tags: nlp, corpus

I am designing an **Automatic text summarizer**. One of the major modules in this project requires **TRAINING CORPUS**. Can someone please help me out by providing **TRAINING CORPUS** or **referring some link to download** it. Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 5):

See [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) by Norvig. He mentions [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists), [British National Corpus](http://www.kilgarriff.co.uk/bnc-readme.html), [Birkbeck spelling error corpus](http://ota.oucs.ox.ac.uk/headers/0643.xml). There's also [Brown Corpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some [Text summarization resources](http://www.summarization.com/), including corpora.
The [Stanford list of NLP/Corpus linguistics resources](http://nlp.stanford.edu/links/statnlp.html) may also help.

Answer (score 0):

See also the [Corpora mailing list](http://gandalf.aksis.uib.no/corpora/), they're a good starting point, and you could also look through their mailing archives for more resources.

Answer (score 0):

British Columbia Conversation Corpus -
http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rjoty/Webpage/resources.htm
You can download it from [here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/nest/lci/bc3/download.html).